# Comparing two excels and inserting a new column value for the matching data sets

Tags: python

I have 2 excel files with 18 columns and almost 100 rows. the column headers are same but the values differ, I want to compare every row from Sheet 1 to every row in Sheet 2, for the rows where the value matches for all the columns I want to insert a new column (which is there already in sheet 2). Want to do this using python.

looking for the code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the pandas library in Python
Use     `pip install pandas`  to install the library (if you haven't already).

Then import the required library     `import pandas as pd`

Now use this to read the excel files     `df1 = pd.read_excel('file1.xlsx') df2 = pd.read_excel('file2.xlsx')`

Perform the comparison and merge the data:    `merged_df = df1.merge(df2, on='column_to_match', suffixes=('_sheet1', '_sheet2'), how='left')`

Assuming 'column_to_match' is the name of the column you want to use for comparison

Replace it with the actual column name you want to use for matching

Now, 'merged_df' will have the rows where the values matched for all columns in both sheets, and you can insert a new column based on the matching rows from Sheet 2.

Finally, write the merged DataFrame back to a new Excel file:    `merged_df.to_excel('output_file.xlsx', index=False)`

***NB:***
Make sure that the column you are using for comparison ('column_to_match' in the example) has unique values for each row in both sheets. Otherwise, the merging process may not work correctly.

If the two DataFrames have different column headers (even though the column names are the same), you may need to ensure that the order of the columns is consistent across both DataFrames or map the column names accordingly.